# Why set.intersection() works on `list` object as argument?

Tags: python

The problem where I met the issue was, how to find the intersection between 2 lists of different lengths without duplicates.

Example:

```
l1 = [3, 8, 9, 6, 5, 3, 7, 8, 2, 10]
l2 = [7, 13, 20, 12, 12, 2, 6, 1, 2, 8, 19, 3, 15, 16, 14, 22, 22, 4, 9, 15, 8, 13]

The solution I suggested was:

res = list(set(l1).intersection(set(l2)))  # [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This works fine, but what also worked was:

```
res = list(set(l1).intersection(l2))  # [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Why intersection of `set` with `list` also worked, does the argument of intersection cast to `set` automatically?

I couldn't find a solution or source online, would appreciate it if someone could shed some light.

Comment: [*"Note, the non-operator versions of union(), intersection(), difference(), and symmetric_difference(), issubset(), and issuperset() methods will accept any iterable as an argument."*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection)

Comment: `help(set.intersection)` should answer your question.

Comment: `set(l1)&set(l2)`, OK  `set(l1)&l2` will give error

Comment: @Epsi95 yes, the next sentence is *"In contrast, their operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note from the [`set()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

> Note, **the non-operator versions of [`union()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union), [`intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection), [`difference()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference), and [`symmetric_difference()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference), [`issubset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset), and [`issuperset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issuperset) methods will accept *any* iterable as an argument**. In contrast, their operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that it accepts any iterable as a parameter, because the algorithm for finding the intersection will be fast as long as at least one of the collections has O(1) searching, and that must be the case if you're calling it as a method on a set.